# Why application with 300 images stops working?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, imageview, out-of-memory

I have created an app which consist 300 images. At the start of app it works snooth, no issue. but when i start the listactivity which load images, my app stop responding. Help me.

This is my **MainActivity** codes.
I copy image zip file from assets folder to internal storage and extract images in internal storage and then show them in gridview of mainactivity.

```
private void createDirs()
{
    File zipFileLoc = new File(storagePath, zipLoc);
    File unzipFileLoc = new File(storagePath, unzipLoc);
    File aksFileLoc = new File(storagePath, aks);
    if(zipFileLoc.exists() && unzipFileLoc.exists() && aksFileLoc.exists()){
        getFromStorage();
    }else{
        zipFileLoc.mkdirs();
        unzipFileLoc.mkdirs();
        aksFileLoc.mkdirs();

        copyAssets();
        unzip();

        getFromStorage();
    }
}

private void copyAssets()
{
    AssetManager assets = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try{
        files = assets.list("");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load images, please restart app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    for(String fileName : files){
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try{
            in = assets.open(fileName);
            File zipOutFile = new File(storagePath + zipLoc, fileName);
            out =new FileOutputStream(zipOutFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
            in.close();
            in = null;
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            out = null;
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load images, please restart app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}

private void unzip()
{
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

    new UnZipTask().execute(storagePath + zipLoc + "/AAGRIKOLISTATUS.zip", storagePath + aks);
}

private class UnZipTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String[] p1)
    {
        String filePath = p1[0];
        String destinationPath = p1[1];

        File archive = new File(filePath);
        try{
            ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(archive);
            for(Enumeration e = zf.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();){
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
                unzipEntry(zf, entry, destinationPath);
            }
            UnzipUtil d = new UnzipUtil(storagePath + zipLoc + "/AAGRIKOLISTATUS.zip", storagePath + aks);
            d.unzip();
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zf, ZipEntry entry, String destinationPath) throws IOException
    {
        if(entry.isDirectory()){
            createDir(new File(destinationPath, entry.getName()));
            return;
        }

        File outputFile = new File(destinationPath, entry.getName());
        if(!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()){
            createDir(outputFile.getParentFile());
        }

        BufferedInputStream inputs = new BufferedInputStream(zf.getInputStream(entry));
        BufferedOutputStream outputs = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

        try{

        }finally{
            outputs.flush();
            outputs.close();
            inputs.close();
        }
    }

    private void createDir(File file)
    {
        if(file.exists()){
            return;
        }

        if(!file.mkdirs()){
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create file " + file);
        }
    }
}

private void getFromStorage()
{
    File file = new File(storagePath, aks);
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        listfile= file.listFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < listfile.length; i++){
            f.add(listfile[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    ad = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gv.setAdapter(ad);
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context cxt)
    {
        this.context = cxt;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return f.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int p1)
    {
        return p1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int p1)
    {
        return p1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int p1, View p2, ViewGroup p3)
    {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.get(p1));
        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));

        return iv;
    }
}
```

Here's my main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#00ff85">

<GridView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/aagrikolistatusphotoGridView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/aagrikolistatusphotocomgoogleandroidgmsadsAdView"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"/>
```

Comment: @user202729 I have uploaded some of my codes in main question.

Comment: post Logcat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you unpack images on the background thread but you load them on main thread what causes UI crash. The solution is to use Glide or Picasso to load images on the background thread. Please read Google Documentation:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#java
and try to use one of them:
Glide:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide
Picasso:
http://square.github.io/picasso/
That should help to solve your problem